# Matching a specific sequence with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match terms which appear as:

```
abcd[_stringiwant_]efgh
```

and

```
abcd[_string_i_want_]efgh
```

I'm able to the first expression with:

```
re.compile('\[_[^\[\]_]*_\]');
```

but this fails to grab the string for the second expression.  Anyone have any suggestions of a regex which works for both?

Answer (score 2):

```
re.compile('\[([^\]]+)\]')
```

That ought to work. Not sure about anything Python specific you'd have to do, but that expression will grab any string between [ and ]

Comment: One python specific note, you should probably use a raw string (`r'\[([^\]]+)\]'`). It saves you from doing ugly `\\` stuff :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I was wondering is it possible to match the sequence '[_' and '_]' while ignoring the characters '_' which do not have a '[' or ']' next to it.

Answer (score 1):

David's regex should work, but I prefer

```
re.compile(r'\[(.+?)\]')
```

for readability. The `+?` is a non-greedy modifier, meaning it will grab the smallest number of characters possible, i.e. it will grab all characters until the first `]`.

Comment: I usually avoid . in regex out of habit, but yeah that's definitely a more readable solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I need a little more info, but I'll take a stab in the dark and say that you're probably using search when you really want findall.  Also, your regex isn't quite right according to what you described (Why underscores?  Do you want it to return empty strings?  If not, then don't use *, use +).  Try this:

```
searcher = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]')
list_of_results = searcher.findall(string_to_search)
```

Comment: Wound up using David's RegEx to make life easier on myself.  Eric's is definitely more elegant, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that:

```
text = '''zza [_stringiwant_] cododo
21321324654654654
aaaaaaaaaa [stringiDONTwant_] bbb
cccc[stringiDONTwantnomore]ddddd
hghghg [_string_i_want_] lumulu
321321
rrree  [_out of need] kjhfkhfg'''

import re

regx = re.compile('(?<=\[_).+?(?=_\])')

print regx.findall(text)
```

result

```
['stringiwant', 'string_i_want']
```